# Checked checkbox from controller

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have angular controller

```
$scope.event = {
  },
  type: {
    checked : false
  }
};
```

I use it like

```
<input id="show" name="type" type="checkbox" ng-model="event.type.checked">
```

When i page reload, my checkbox property checked disappear. How can i do condition, if event.type.checked == true, checkbox must be checked, else unchecked. Please, help

Comment: $scope.event = {
  },
  type: {
    checked : false
  }
};
There's an extra curly brackett in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLewjo6g/).

Here works:

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.event = {
        type: {
            checked: true
        }
    };
}]);
```

Probably just your `$scope.event` has an extra curly bracket.

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure, but this doc may help you

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked